# Event handler for read serial port never triggers

Tags: c#, console-application

**Goal:**

Trying to write a string to a serial port, read it, then print it to console

**Code:**

```
// for waiting until event is detected
private static ManualResetEvent waitHandle = new ManualResetEvent(false);

public Driver()
{
    // create new serial port
    comPort = new SerialPort("COM1", 9600, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);
    // add event handler
    comPort.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(comPort_DataReceived);  
    // configure port
    comPort.DtrEnable = true;
    comPort.RtsEnable = true;
    comPort.ReadTimeout = 3000;
    // open port          
    comPort.Open();

    // send string through port
    string command = "test \n";
    byte[] MyMessage = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(command);
    comPort.Write(MyMessage, 0, MyMessage.Length);

    // wait until event is detected
    waitHandle.WaitOne();
}

private void comPort_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    // Write data to buffer and stop wait
    Console.WriteLine(comPort.ReadExisting());
    waitHandle.Set();
}
```

**Issue:**

Write to serial seems to work fine ([confirmed by using Serial Port Monitor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2AE97.png)) but "comPort_DataReceived" never gets called

If I change my code and add

```
while(true)
{
    Console.WriteLine(comPort.ReadExisting());
}
```

Right after the "comPort.Write(MyMessage, 0, MyMessage.Length);" line so that I'm polling instead of waiting for the event handler then a whole lot of nothing gets written

If I try polling this way

```
while (true)
{
    Byte[] buf = new Byte[2048];
    comPort.Read(buf, 0, 2048);
    Console.WriteLine(buf.ToString());
}
```

It just times out (System.TimeoutException: 'The operation has timed out.'
).

I'm not sure where I am going wrong/why I am unable to read from the serial port

Comment: Check if there is device writing to serial port as a response to your data written

Comment: Serial Port Monitor can also send data directly, try to use it communication to your device directly, and see how does it response. BTW,  please note that some of device is controlled by on XON/XOFF, not CTS/RTS.

Comment: The Handshake property is very important, the default only ever works by accident.  If you are going to control the DTR and RTS handshake lines yourself then you must pick Handshake.None.   Do not set the ReadTimeout property until *after* you got it working, 3 seconds doesn't give you enough time to look at anything.  You must get confidence that the hardware configuration is correct with another program, like Putty or HyperTerminal.  If they don't receive anything then your program never will.  If they do then you can look for mistakes in your own code.

Comment: Tomassino - Ya that was the issue. Also I was under the impression that I could write to the serial port with this program and then be able to read what I wrote so I was getting doubly confused  



J.C - Ended up using Putty to send data instead of Serial Port Monitor and that helped me catch my problem  

Hans Passant - I tried playing around with the handshake property and it had no effect. Ended up using Putty to catch a hardware issue

Thanks everyone :)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, from what I see it looks like there is no device listening on serial port. Then, if you write something to serial port it does not mean that the same data will occur as a received data. This data is `outgoing data`. If you want to receive data there must be another device connected to that serial port and sending data as a response to your data written.

Comment: Perhaps this should be a comment, not an answer ;)

Comment: I added a comment before with no response so I will see

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was a hardware issue (no device was writing to serial port) coupled with a misunderstanding (thinking I could write to a serial port and then read what I wrote from within the same program)